# JSON + AngularJS

Tags: json, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

How can I iterate over this JSON values with AngularJS ng-repeat?

```
{
    "timestamp": "Wed Apr 02 2014, 19:03:19",
    "test": [
        441.02,
        null,
        null,
        460.99,
        485.91,
        501,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null
    ],
    "test1": [
        437,
        null,
        null,
        464.989,
        488.52,
        499.996,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null
    ],
    "test3": [
        10.85,
        null,
        null,
        10.9,
        10.9,
        10.9,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null
    ]
}
```

And this is the controller Im using:

```
var myJson = angular.module('myJson', []);

function PostsCtrlAjax($scope, $http)
{

$http({method: 'POST', url: 'graphs.json'}).success(function(data)

    {
        $scope.values = data; // response data
    });


}
```

I wanna show all the values in test/1/2/3 in some html bootstrap table.

And also, how can I store all those values in some array[] with JavaScript?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Could you please give the approximate layout you want to have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what you need:

**HTML**

```
<table class="table" ng-controller="PostsCtrlAjax">
  <tr ng-repeat="key in keys">
    <td>{{key}}</td>
    <td ng-repeat="value in values[key] track by $index">{{value}}<td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Since your tests arrays contain duplicate items (nulls), you should add `track by $index` to internal loop. It is [recommended](http://docs.angularjs.org/error/ngRepeat/dupes) way to avoid duplicates issue.

**JavaScript**

```
angular.module('myJson', []).
  controller('PostsCtrlAjax', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http) {
    $http({
      method: 'GET',
      url: 'graphs.json'
    }).success(function(data) {
        // Form array of test names for external ng-repeat that will render rows
        // Take only the properties that represent tests (filter out timestamp property)
        $scope.keys = Object.keys(data).filter(function(value) {
          return value.indexOf('test') === 0;
        })
        // Place data to scope in order to render cells in internal ng-repeat
        $scope.values = data; // response data
    });
  }]);
```

Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/yKj0QzowkIfNKDO1ECnJ?p=preview